# Break if loop in cypress

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, cypress

we have a scenario as below

```
iterate over name elements in the page
 if(name.text() == expName)
{
name.click()
exit from if loop
}
else
{
createName()
}
```

how do i implement this in cypress, as the return false is not exiting from the if loop.
here is the code which i have tried

```
export function addProtocol(protocolName, protocolStatus) {
  let flag = "false";
  subject.view({ name: "ProtocolsExplorerList" }).as('currentView');
  cy.get('@currentView').find('td textarea').each($el => {
    cy.wrap($el).invoke('val').then($value => {
      console.log("valueee:" + $value);
      if ($value == protocolName) {
        cy.get($el).click();
        flag = "true";
        return false;
      }
    })
  })

  if (flag == "false") {

    subject.button({ class: "New" }).click();
    subject.field("Name").type(protocolName);
    subject.field("Status").setCaption(protocolStatus);
    save();
    cy.contains(protocolName).click();

  }

}
```

Any suggestions please?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you resolution to this requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html#Return-early) specifically says:

> You can stop the .each() loop early by returning false in the callback
> function.

So there's likely something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't return from `each` callback with `false`. You return from the `then` callback with `false`. `then` callbacks normally run asynchronously, meaning that the callback executes after `each` is done iterating.

I'm not familiar with cypress, but assuming they implement the [iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterator_protocol) on their collections you could use:

```
const textareas = cy.get('@currentView').find('td textarea');

for (const $el of textareas) {
  const $value = await cy.wrap($el).invoke('val');
  console.log("valueee:" + $value);
  if ($value == protocolName) {
    cy.get($el).click();
    flag = "true";
    break;
  }
}
```

You'll have to make the wrapping function an `async function` to enable the use of `await`.